# A dense parallelizable submanifold in any manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In *Riemannian Geometry* of Peter Petersen, he says that any manifold contains an open dense set $O \subset M$ where $T O=O \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is trivial. I'm confused about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to prove this. Here is a construction that uses a Riemannian metric.

We will focus on the connected case: the general case follows by doing this construction in all connected components.
Consider any complete Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ and fix a point $p$.
Let $C_p$ be the [cut-locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_locus_(Riemannian_manifold)) of $p$.
Then it is known that $C_p$ has measure zero and that $M\setminus C_p$ is a contractible dense open subset.
As an open subset, it is a submanifold, and as a contractible manifold, it is parallelizable.
In particular, $O = M\setminus C_p$ is a solution to your problem.

Comment: So can every manifold can be equipped with a complete Riemannian metric?

Comment: It is an interesting exercise to show that any Riemannian metric $g$ is conformal to a complete Riemannian metric, that is, there exists a smooth function $f$ such that $e^f g$ is complete.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand completely.